# Mazda Lantis 323 1997: OBDI or OBDII?

Tags: tools, electronic-control-module

I'm still trying to figure out if my 1997 Mazda Lantis 323 GLX 1.8L DHOC Manual  is OBD 1 or 2.  It's supposedly similar to the Protege of the same year [and it says on autozone](http://www.autozone.com/repairinfo/repairguide/repairGuideContent.jsp?pageId=0996b43f80cb0f48):

> In order to retrieve the trouble code(s), you must have the Mazda system selector 49 B019 9A0 and self diagnosis checker (a digital readout tool) 49 H018 9A1 or an equivalent OBD I compliant scan tool for 1990-95 (except 1994-95 626 with ATX and 1995 Protege and Millenia) models. For 1994-95 626 with ATX, 1995 Protege and Millenia and all 1996-98 Models, you must have an OBD I (1994-95 626 with ATX only) or OBD II compliant scan tool.

Here is what the connector looks like:

[image]

**EDIT**

So I spoke with my mechanic who said it's OBD1, but that doesn't really seem correct to me because I took a look at the scanner he uses, [the Carman Lite](http://www.auto-tool-shop.com/carman-scan-lite-p-230.html), and it doesn't support OBD1.  He uses a Mazda 17 bin to OBD2 adapter cable to connect, and web page for the scanner lists the following protocols:

> 1. Communication Protocol Compatibility
>
>    - ISO 9141-2, ISO-14230,
>    - SAE J1850 (PWM, VPW) ,
>    - KWP2000
>    - CAN BUS Communication support

Further down the page it lists:

> - OBD-II (ISO 9142-2)
> - OBD-II (SAE-J1850 VPW, PWM)
> - KWP-2000
> - CAN
> - SAE-J1587 for commercial vehicle

So it must be one of these, but I don't know which one...

Comment: The protocols are decided by the SAE (Society of Automotive Engineers) of America and are adopted globally. OBDII is for petrol cars made from the year 2000, and 2004 for diesel cars. If it does not have a 16 pin DLC it is not strictly OBDII, although you will have a very small number of vehicles that are all but OBDII because of the DLC. Ford had thier own protocol for a little while, Mazda as an outfit are owned by Ford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://forscan.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5&p=5) which might help you where you need to go. Non-US vehicles have that funky connector on them instead of the standard OBDII DLC. There are four wires you need to connect from an OBDII style reader to your 17-pin port. One of these two diagrams should be the breakdown:

[image: From the FORScan forum]
[image: From the FORScan forum]

**NOTE:** I know the writing is Cyrillic, but the pin-out should be evident.

Comment: So it actually is obd2 but just with a non-standard connector?

Comment: Paulster2  is Correct. Follow his answer and you'll get the codes.

Comment: I just ran across this which claims that all cars imported to Israel prior to 2003 are OBD1:  http://www.totalcardiagnostics.com/support/Knowledgebase/Article/View/3/0/is-my-car-obd-2-compatible-and-supported-by-obd-software#israel

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes ... Does your car have in-cat or after-cat O2 sensors? If so, I'll give it about a 98% chance it is OBDII compliant. My suggestion to you is, try the above approach. It wouldn't take much to make it happen, just some spare wire and connectors if you already have (or can borrow) an OBDII scan tool.

Comment: I think it only has a single pre-cat O2 sensor, but I'll check.

Comment: So I was finally able to connect to the ECU using the FORScan software and the OBDLink SX I picked up on amazon.  Basically, it uses the K Line ISO 9141-2 protocol on pin 7 of the OBDII connector, but there's something strange about how it packages it's data and standard OBDII software like OBDwiz can't talk to it.  The only module found by FORScan was the Powertrain Control Module and it's showing an error on the MAF, which is what I suspected.

Comment: I'm glad you got something to work ... what a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1994 Mazda B2300 p/u. Engine light comes off and on, I would like to diagnose the problem. The Mazda book says to use a CAN OBDll diagnostic scan tool. The Mazda book also says to use a selector tool 49-B019-9a0 and connect self diagnosis check tool 49-B018-9a1. I need an adaptor to connect from the eec test plug to my OBDll, would appreciate your help. Thanks Dan

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you'd like to ask a question, please use the "Ask Question" link in the upper right.

Answer (score -1):

Its pre OBD2,  in the attached video link. It show how to OBD2 elm scanner. Wiring on Mazda 323 different from Mazda 626, both using different protocol.

https://youtu.be/DjD3QpkxVz8